# How to import "HdfsClient" in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hadoop, anaconda, pyhdfs-client

I'm new in python & I'm trying to connect with Hadoop HDFS system. I got the following reference code as which I tried to implement it, but it's showed error while importing the package.

```
from pyarrow import HdfsClient

# Using libhdfs
hdfs = HdfsClient('192.168.0.119', '50070', 'cloudera', driver='libhdfs')
```

> Error: **ImportError: cannot import name 'HdfsClient'**

I even tried to install it using "*pip*", but

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement HdfsClient
>   (from versi ons: ) No matching distribution found for HdfsClient

then I tried using "*conda*", but again

> Collecting package metadata: done Solving environment: failed
>
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
>   current cha nnels:
>
> - hdfsclient
>
> Current channels:
>
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
>
> To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package
>   you're looking for, navigate to
>
> ```
> https://anaconda.org
> ```
>
> and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Actually I'm trying to connect to the HUE using:

IP Add    -> 192.168.0.119

Port name -> 50070

Username  -> cloudera

password  -> cloudera

But it's not working out. Can anyone please suggest to connect it in a better way or how to import "HdfsClient" package in Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

`HDFSClient` is deprecated. You might want to use `pyarrow.hdfs.connect`.
Also try `pip freeze` to see if the relevant library is installed in your python environment or not.
ex.

```
from pyarrow import hdfs
hdfs.connect('192.168.0.119', 50070, 'cloudera', driver='libhdfs')
```

Comment: Thanks @kapil but it still showing error, `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`. And I do have password as well for connecting to the hadoop & there is no parameter for password in hdfs.connect() method.

Comment: You get this error while making hdfs connection or while reading a file. can you paste your code for more clarity.

Comment: No, I'm not reading any file, I just used your "**pyarrow**" code (mentioned above by you) & simply tried to execute as all the details inside hdfs.connect() method are all same.